# How to serialize Arraylist form

Tags: jquery, forms, jsp, serialization

I am using following form to serialize and submit but it is not submitting the form as given

**Html**

```
<form action="" id="post_message_form">
    <textarea name="message" style="width:100%;height:80px" id="text_message" cssClass="form-control"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="postImageseList[0].largePicPath" class="img-dtl" value="/img/post/large/0020603xpd4ps7ew_1_7gwy2kc44f141777.jpg" />
     <input type="hidden" name="postImageseList[1].largePicPath" class="img-dtl" value="/img/post/large/0020603xpd4ps7ew_1_7gwy2kc44f141666.jpg" />
    <button type="submit" id="submit_status_button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#post_message_form").on("submit", function (f) {
      f.preventDefault();
      console.log($("#post_message_form").serialize());
      alert($("#post_message_form").serialize());
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'PostMessage',
          data: $("#post_message_form").serialize(),
          dataType: "text html",
          success: function (data) {

          }
      }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
          alert("Error");
          alert('error status:' + status);
      });
  });
```

Field `name="postImageseList[0].largePicPath"` is dynamically generate field it may be 0 or more.
How to serialize above form.

I tried it **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/seb0k7np/)**

Comment: Seems to be ok. "url: 'PostMessage'" looks weird

Comment: You need to give the proper url in ajax call. Then it should work fine.

Comment: What is the problem with PostMessage

Comment: @user3263194 Is above code is correct

Comment: can you please explain what is 'PostMessage'?
Are you referring to some jsp page here? then you need to add .jsp

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/seb0k7np/1/ please see Updated url

Comment: @Ferret How to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Add a name attribute to the dynamically generated fields.

Try using the below code:

```
var formData = $('#form').serializeObject();
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://www.smsiland.com/PostMessage',
      data: formData.serialize(),
      dataType: "text html",
      success: function (data) {

      }
  })
updated fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/seb0k7np/4/
```

Comment: here var formData = $('#form').serializeObject(); it is showing `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`